# Using a white list to enable user based applications in windows 10 deployments

Tags: windows, powershell, whitelist

I have made a variation to a popular PS script that removes user based apps. My script uses a whitelist to determine what not to remove. My whitelist looks like this..

```
store
calc
camera
stickynotes
```

The script is called during the SCCM Task sequence to deploy a machine. This is the script...

```
$whitelist = Get-Content -path $PSScriptRoot\whitelist.txt
$AllApps = @(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers)
$AllProvApps = @(Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online)

foreach ($App in $AllApps) {

   foreach ($item in $whitelist) {  
   
      if ($App.name -like "*$item*") { $App = "" } 

   } 
      
   if ($App -ne "") {Remove-AppxPackage $App}
      
}

foreach ($ProvApp in $AllProvApps) {

   foreach ($item in $whitelist) {  
   
      if ($ProvApp.name -like "*$item*") { $ProvApp = "" } 

   } 
      
   if ($ProvApp -ne "") {Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage $ProvApp}
      
}
```

The results make be believe it 'Sort' of works... I have a calculator but nothing else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As from my comment, this is all you need basically:

Assuming that the content of `whitelist.txt` contains the following (as you mentioned in your question):

```
store
calc
camera
stickynotes
```

All you need to do is this:

```
$whitelist = (Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\whitelist.txt | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }) -join '|'
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch $whitelist } | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -notmatch $whitelist } | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
```

Explanation:

- We get the file content that is not null or white space and join it together with `|` to create the regex string
- We get all `AppxPackages` and `AppxProvisionedPackages` that don't match the regex and remove them

Comment: Thanks @SimonS, I'll take it for a test drive :)

Comment: Hi @SimonS, tried your script and found that the only caveat seems to be the whitelist must not have any CR/LF at the end, otherwise you get something like store|calc|camera||| (depending how many carriage returns I guess) If my white list is compliant, it works a treat :)  I tried adding  `(Get-Content -path $PSScriptRoot\whitelist.txt).trim()` but that didnt normalise the whitelist in a way that changed the symptom.

Comment: @paul.sanders you can change the line to the following, then it will only import lines that have a value `$whitelist = (Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\whitelist.txt | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }) -join '|'`

Answer (score 1):

Your script is wrong, and the fault in it makes it hard to be understood. But I guessed what you are trying to do in the end, you are trying to uninstall all apps not listed in whitelist, this is very simple, I had fixed your code, now it's working:

```
[string[]]$whitelist = Get-Content -path $PSScriptRoot\whitelist.txt
$AllApps = @(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers)
$AllProvApps = @(Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online)

foreach ($App in $AllApps) {
    if ($whitelist -notcontains $App.packagefullname) {Remove-AppxPackage $App}
}
foreach ($ProvApp in $AllProvApps) {
    if ($whitelist -notcontains $ProvApp.packagename) {Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage $ProvApp}
}
```

As Get-Content returns each line as a separate string by default, use [string[]] will create an [array] with each line as a [string] element, it would be then easy to check containment conditions by using -contains and -notcontains operator, the results of the operators are boolean (true or false) values.

The if condition means the app is not contained in the whitelist.

---

### ***Update***

The above code will only work if full names of apps are supplied, to get full names, run `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers` to get all apps, it's a long list, so better redirect the output to a file:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Out-File "C:\path\to\text\file.txt"
```

You can also filter to make it only output the full names of apps by:

```
(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers).packagefullname
```

For provisioned appx packages, use this:

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

To output to console

```
(Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online).PackageName
```

To display only packagenames

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Out-File "C:\path\to\file.txt"
```

To redirect the output to a text file.

But better use this:

```
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Export-Csv "C:\Path\To\File.csv"
```

to export it as a csv file, so next time you can use it in PowerShell by simply:

```
$csv=Import-Csv "C:\Path\To\File.csv"
```

And the full code:

```
[string[]]$whitelist = get-content -path $psscriptroot\whitelist.txt
[array]$apps=(get-appxpackage -allusers).packagefullname
[array]$provapps=(get-appxprovisionedpackage -online).packagename
$approved=@()
foreach ($item in $whitelist) {
    foreach ($app in $apps) {
        if ($app -match $item -and $approved -notcontains $app) {$approved+=$app}
    }
    foreach ($provapp in $provapps) {
        if ($provapp -match $item -and $approved -notcontains $provapp) {$approved+=$provapp}
    }
}
$whitelist=$approved
foreach ($app in $apps) {
    if ($whitelist -notcontains $app) {remove-appxpackage -package $app -allusers}
}
foreach ($provapp in $provapps) {
    if ($whitelist -notcontains $provapp) {remove-appxprovisionedpackage -online -packagename $provapp}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dirty I know but it resolved the problem for me!

```
where-object {($_.name –notlike “*store*”) -and ($_.name –notlike "*Calc*") -and ($_.name –notlike "*Camera*")
```

I like Xeнεi Ξэnвϵς suggestion but think I ran into an issue with the path of the white list that results in everything being uninstalled. When I have more time I will revisit it.

Comment: Your code is really bad, first the resultant objects of `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage` don't have a property named "name", instead they have two properties with name in them: `DisplayName` and `PackageName`, `Get-AppxPackages` results have three names: `Name`, `PackageFullName` and `PackageFamilyName`; Try this command`(Get-AppxProvisionedPackage).name` and it will not output anything. For AppxPackage you need to use .PackageFulName to get fullnames, for AppxProvisionedPackage you need .PackageName to get fullnames instead.

Comment: Then, to achieve the same result of your code, for AppxPackages, use this:`(Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers).PackageFullName | where-object {$_ -notmatch "store|calc|camera|stickynotes"} | foreach-object {remove-appxpackage -package $_ -AllUsers}`

Comment: `(Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online).PackageName | where-object {$_ -notmatch "store|calc|camera|stickynotes"} | foreach-object {remove-appxprovisionedpackage -packagename $_}` for AppxProvisionedPackages

Comment: The downside of this: you have to specify all whitelist app shortnames in one line in -notmatch session, use `|` to separate the app shortnames, if you have a long list, the code would be very ugly.

Comment: Hey, I'm new to PS... I know my code is bad.. that's why i'm here :)

Comment: @paul.sanders It's not even bad - that comment bothered me as well. You got the principle - `Where-Object` is in this case much better than a lot of foreaches for such a simple task.